# Dynamically appended elements don't have quite the same position as there sibling elements that were inserted on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I load 40 elements on page load, when the user presses a button another 40 are appended(same element types and CSS classes). The 40 dynamically loaded elements have less space between them than the first 40 elements that loaded on page load ( even though they shouldn't since they have the same styling). I cant't get them to work, any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: could you add your code please?

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to provide a code-snippet that is relevant to your problem, so that we can help you fix it.

But I'll take a stab in the dark, and assume that your elements are styled as `inline-block`s, which would mean that if there's whitespace in your HTML between the initially shown elements, it will be rendered as a single space () between the elements on the page.

When you create the dynamic elements on the page, (probably with JS?), there will be no whitespace in the new markup, which means that the elements are displayed right next to each other, instead of with a space between them.

**EDIT**: Example given below. The divs inside `#spaced` are written like you normally would write HTML; with  whitespace denoting hierarchical semantics.

In `#together`, the HTML for the divs is written first with an HTML comment instead of whitespace, and secondly with nothing in the markup between the elements.

Depending on your needs, you might prefer using `float:` instead of `display:inline-block` for your elements, if you don't want to change the HTML.

```css
.ib
{
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background: #123;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='spaced'>
    <div class='ib'>
    </div>
    <div class='ib'>
    </div>
    <div class='ib'>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='together'>
    <div class='ib'>
    </div><!--
 --><div class='ib'>
    </div><div class='ib'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing any code, its just hard to pick the right code since i don't what is causing the problem. Yes indeed they are inline-block elements, i am gonna take your advice and check for spaces thanks!

Comment: It worked, I had space between my initially loaded elements, how stupid can i be for not realizing this! Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. I also added an example to further demonstrate the problem and the solution.